# How to match a line having 2 or more caracters, and that can have spaces, on a defined length?

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to match a string beginning by an F or a C,

The length must be 13,

I can include spaces, numbers and capital letters, but I must have at least 2 non-space characters in the string.

I can't find how to fuse those conditions, could you please help me ?

I am using PCRE(PHP)

I tried a line looking like this:

```
^([C,F][0-9A-Z])(.*[0-9A-Z ]{1,12})$
```

But it seems it matches whenever I have 2 or more characters, even if the length is below 13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?=.{13}$)[CF] *(?:[0-9A-Z] *)+$
```

Or

```
^(?=.{13}$)[CF]\s*(?:[0-9A-Z]\s*)+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/euW50d/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{13}$)` - the string must be 13 chars long (add `(?s)` before `^` if the string may have line breaks)
- `[CF]` - `C` or `F`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(?:[0-9A-Z]\s*)+`  - 1 or more repetitions of

  - `[0-9A-Z]` - an uppercase ASCII letter or digit
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

Note that since the `[CF]` already matches a non-space char, the `(?:[0-9A-Z]\s*)+` already makes sure there is another non-space char later in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `^[CF](?=([ ]*[0-9A-Z][ ]*){1,})([ 0-9A-Z]{12})$`

Comment: One remark: placing empty string matching patterns at the start and end of an indefinitely quantified group (as in `([ ]*[0-9A-Z][ ]*){1,}`) leads to more backtracking. This is bad practice, one should make sure the regex matches chunks of texts that do not start with the same char(s) type (as best practice). See my answer how this can be achieved.